# Does the LEGO Mario app support three player?

Tags: software, super-mario

There are 3 playable characters currently in the LEGO Mario theme (Mario, Luigi, and Peach).

[image: Characters]

The app makes a two player mode available. Is it possible to play with all three characters in the app?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue recently. Unfortunately, this is not currently supported in the LEGO Mario app. Any two characters can be used together ([even matching characters](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17017/are-both-a-mario-and-a-luigi-required-for-2-player-mode)), but you can't connect more than two characters simultaneously.

This was clear in the app update that added support for Peach (emphasis added):

> LEGO Peach comes with a bunch of new reactions and can be connected to **either LEGO® Mario™ or LEGO® Luigi™** (sets are sold separately) to win bonus coins for teamwork.

Subsequent updates have not upgraded the multiplayer mode to support additional players.